# How to apply css to the email template in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, automationstudio, email-studio

I have created emails from email templates available in the marketing cloud.

To add CSS to an email I have used HTML content block and added CSS inside the `<style> [CSS here] </style>`tag.

In the preview window of the marketing cloud email is rendering as expected it's applying CSS but when I am sending that email I have received the email without CSS applied.

why is this happening? I have created almost twenty emails all of them are not applying CSS

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the CSS on a Code View Tab under Type-Template.

You are adding the CSS on a Type-Template-Based Email HTML block which the email will strip the styling tag.

[image]

[image]